Typescript - Create a subset of discriminated union as a discriminated union
Is there a way to create a subset discriminated union by picking some fields from another discriminated union?
For example:
type Listing = {
  type: 'rent';
  title: string;
  userId: string;

  dailyPrice: number;
  monthlyPrice: number;
  
} | {
  type: 'sell',
  title: string;
  userId: string;
  
  sellPrice: number;
}

into
type ListingBrief {
  type: 'rent';
  dailyPrice: number;
  monthlyPrice: number;
} | {
  type: 'sell';
  sellPrice: number;
}

So what I want is something like Pick<Listing, 'type' | 'dailyPrice' | 'monthlyPrice' | 'salePrice'>. But seems Typescript doesn't allow picking fields that only exist in one type i.e dailyPrice, monthlyPrice, and salePrice. Fields like title, userId can be picked because they exist in all of the types.


Typescript doesn't allow picking fields that only exist in one type

You can just write your own MyPick utility type.
type MyPick<T, K extends T extends infer R ? keyof R : never> = 
    T extends infer R 
    ? { [P in K as P extends keyof R ? P : never]: R[P]; } 
    : never
;

type Result = MyPick<Listing, 'type' | 'dailyPrice' | 'monthlyPrice' | 'sellPrice'>;


Not sure about what you're asking for, however you can split the original union in two different types:
type ListingRent = {
  type: 'rent';
  title: string;
  userId: string;

  dailyPrice: number;
  monthlyPrice: number;
}

type ListingSell = {
  type: 'sell',
  title: string;
  userId: string;
  
  sellPrice: number;
}

type Listing = ListingRent | ListingSell;

At this point, the result is straightforward:
type ListingRentBrief = Pick<ListingRent, 'type' | 'dailyPrice' | 'monthlyPrice'>

type ListingSellBrief = Pick<ListingSell, 'type' | 'salePrice'>

type ListingBrief = ListingRentBrief | ListingSellBrief;

Is it what you're expecting? if not, I'll remove it.

Not really, because for your answer requires manually breaking down the Union first and re-union it again after picking the fields. What I want is utility type that does that automatically and generically. Something like type ListingBrief = SomeUtil<Listing, 'type' | 'dailyPrice | 'monthlyPrice | 'salePrice'>
